# An exhaustive list of all graphics cards by all vendors ever put on mac?

Tags: gpu

Where can I get an exhaustive list of all graphics cards ever put in a mac? Or at least in the last 10years...

I am NOT interested in mobile devices, just desktops and laptops.

Comment: http://www.everymac.com has all the data - just not laid out for easy access… though you can search by almost every other conceivable parameter

Comment: @Tetsujin Oh, I think that might do the job!

Answer (score 1):

[Mactracker.app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mactracker/id430255202?mt=12)

Has a list going back all the way to the beginning.

Comment: Carefull. With Mactracker won't get a list of all graphics cards, you will get a list of all macs. But, you have to navigate model by model to see what's the card in a given model.

Comment: I figured the OP could see that its not a list and would have to navigate.

Comment: Yes, definitely not gonna work in my case as it will take me forever but +1 cause it is quite useful anyway and I didn't know it...

Answer (score 0):

So just for ease, as of this moment the most complete list that I've found thanks to Tetsujin's comment is found in http://www.everymac.com/ultimate-mac-sort/?sort=all-intel-macs under the Graphics Card tab. This is a list of all cards in intel based macs (>G3):

3D Rage II+

 *AMD FirePro D300 x2*
 AMD FirePro D300/D500 x2*
 AMD FirePro D500 x2*
 ATI PCI*
 GeForce 320M
 GeForce 6600
 GeForce 6600 LE
 GeForce 7300 GT
 GeForce 7300GT
 GeForce 8600M GT
 GeForce 8800 GS
 GeForce 9400M
 GeForce 9400M*
 GeForce 9600M GT*
 GeForce FX 5200 Ultra
 GeForce FX Go5200
 GeForce GT 120
 GeForce GT 130
 GeForce GT 330M*
 GeForce GT 650M
 GeForce GT 650M*
 GeForce GT 750M
 GeForce GT 750M*
 GeForce GT 755M
 GeForce GTX 660M
 GeForce GTX 675MX
 GeForce GTX 775M
 GeForce2 MX
 GeForce2 MX TwinView
 GeForce2 MX*
 GeForce4 420 Go
 GeForce4 440 Go
 GeForce4 MX
 GeForce4 MX*
 HD Graphics 3000
 HD Graphics 4000
 HD Graphics 5000
 Intel GMA 950
 Intel GMA X3100
 Iris 5100
 Iris Pro 5200
 Mobility Radeon
 Mobility Radeon 7500
 Mobility Radeon 9000
 Mobility Radeon 9200
 Mobility Radeon 9550
 Mobility Radeon 9600
 Mobility Radeon 9700
 Radeon 7500
 Radeon 7500*
 Radeon 9000 Pro
 Radeon 9000 Pro*
 Radeon 9200
 Radeon 9600
 Radeon 9600 Pro
 Radeon 9600 XT
 Radeon 9650
 Radeon HD 2400 XT
 Radeon HD 2600 PRO
 Radeon HD 2600 XT
 Radeon HD 4670
 Radeon HD 4850
 Radeon HD 5670
 Radeon HD 5750
 Radeon HD 5770
 Radeon HD 6490M*
 Radeon HD 6630M
 Radeon HD 6750M
 Radeon HD 6750M*
 Radeon HD 6770M
 Radeon HD 6770M*
 Radeon HD 6970M
 Radeon X1300
 Radeon X1600
 Radeon X600 Pro
 Radeon X600 XT
 Rage 128
 Rage 128 GL
 Rage 128 Pro
 Rage 128 Pro*
 Rage 128 Ultra
 Rage 128 VR 2D/3D
 Rage 128*
 Rage IIc*
 Rage LT
 Rage Mobility
 Rage Mobility 128
 Rage Pro
 Rage Pro LT
 Rage Pro Turbo